# HTML5 Local Storage with Cordova / Phonegap on Android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm looking for a method to use a specific identifier for a device, so I can have some control on app usage remotely.

From the phonegap docs:

```
device.uuid
```

Would return a 64bit Integer as a string.

I have heard that this can change on app update and is generally not reliable.  So I created a random number when the app is first launched, then saved this in local storage.

I am unsure of how reliable this would be on:

1) Device SW Update

2) App Update

Is there a better way to do this, so as to preserve a unique identifier in situations as described above?  Would using an SQL database overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this situation and i have generated unique id as a combination of

- current device timestamp
- device uuid

it is somewhat efficient way for generating unique id.

> **Update:**

**IOS:**

In case of Apple devices which have ios versions; their UUID will never change. The Unique Device ID will always stay the same, and the property is `read-only`.

**Android:**

In case of Android devices user can actually delete whatever file/UUID you use for tracking (not easy, but doable), if your requirement is to track devices.So, perhaps, go for telephony ID, Mac ID or a combination of both.

**`device.uuid`:**

And you are using `device.uuid` of phonegap which is different from native UUID.

> **from phonegap doc:**
>
> iPhone: The uuid on iOS is not unique to a device, but varies for each
>   application, for each installation. It changes if you delete and
>   re-install the app, and possibly also when you upgrade iOS, or even
>   upgrade your app per version (apparent in iOS 5.1). The uuid is not a
>   reliable value.
>
> Android: Returns a random 64-bit integer (as a string, again!)
>            The integer is generated on the device's first boot.

Comment: generating the udid is not the problem, the problem is that udid persisting across device updates / app updates